# How to disable ReSharper property code autocomplete/code snippet

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

In Visual Studio if you type 'prop' and then double tap the 'tab' key it adds a property code snippet.

I used to use the default one in Visual Studio all the time but since installing ReSharper it's overridden it with a ReSharper snippet that drives me insane because it works in a weird way that just doesn't work for me.

I want to switch back to the VS default one but can't work out how to disable it and switch back. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper uses 'Live Templates' which override VS snippets if they use the same shortcut.

Using Resharper 2017.1, to disable a specific live template, go to the menu ReSharper > Tools > Template Explorer...

Then in the C# scope, find and untick 'prop'.

You may need to restart Visual Studio for the change to take effect.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try out your answer sooner. Solved it. Thank you.